# How do I type a model to act like an object in loopback?

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs

I have a loopback model which (in many cases) is represented in a raw json form of itself.  e.g.

```
@model()
class SomeModel extends Entity {
  @property({ type: 'string' })
  id?: string;
}
```

... in raw json would be

```
interface IRawSomeModel {id?: string}
```

Is there any way to get the `IRawSomeModel` programmatically?

One way I can think of is to combine the two, but it's a lot of extra work having to repeat everything e.g.

```
export interface IRawSomeModel {id?: string}

@model()
export class SomeModel extends Entity implements IRawSomeModel {
  @property({ type: 'string' })
  id?: string;
}
```

Ultimately, what I'm looking for is something along the syntax of `RawObjectFormOfModel<SomeModel>`

The point of all this would to be able to have code like so:

```
const obj: RawObjectFormOfModel<SomeModel> = {}; // no error about missing class functions
obj.id = "test"
```

What is the best way to get a raw object type representation of models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can find to do this is to create an interface and implement it.

```
export interface IRawSomeModel {id?: string}

@model()
export class SomeModel extends Entity implements IRawSomeModel {
  @property({ type: 'string' })
  id?: string;
}
```

I'm hoping I can find a way to take the decorator information and use it to generate the interface.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods available in Entity class in lb4. **toJSON()** and **toObject()**. Both of them return plain object representation of model class. You can utilize them for this purpose.

From the dts definition "model.d.ts"

```
/**
 * Serialize into a plain JSON object
 */
toJSON(): Object;
/**
 * Convert to a plain object as DTO
 */
toObject(options?: Options): Object;
```

Comment: I'm looking for type checking, not type conversion.

Comment: Hey @SephReed, may I know the use case you are trying to solve ? Just want to make sure that I can provide right solution to you based on that.

Comment: The case is shown above, like so `RawObjectFormOfModel<SomeModel>`, where that is a type.  The point is to have typechecking for the properties, but given this info `toJSON(): Object;` it would appear it is not possible.  Not even loopbacks built in functions do it.